# Extract response data from custom LLM in langchain through callbacks?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

When writing an integration for [a custom LLM](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/llms/custom_llm) in langchain. Is it possible to add support for collecting information from the actually requests through means of the [callbacks](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/callbacks/) as they exist for example for OpenAI through `get_openai_callback` (see [docs](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/callbacks/langchain.callbacks.manager.get_openai_callback.html) and [this example about tracking token usage](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/llms/token_usage_tracking)).

Concretely I would like to be able to extract response data like `stop_reason` from the Watsonx granite model response. I am using the `ibm-watson-machine-learning` package which provides the `WatsonxLLM` class that implements `LLM` from langchain.

I have without success tried to replicate something similar as done [for openai inside the langchain library](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/c0f4b95aa9961724ab4569049b4c3bc12ebbacfc/libs/langchain/langchain/callbacks/manager.py#L62):

```
class _WatsonXCallbackHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def on_llm_end(self, response: LLMResult, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        """Run when LLM ends running."""
        if response.llm_output is None:
            return None

    def __copy__(self) -> "_WatsonXCallbackHandler":
        """Return a copy of the callback handler."""
        return self

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo: Any) -> "_WatsonXCallbackHandler":
        """Return a deep copy of the callback handler."""
        return self

watsonx_callback_var: ContextVar[Optional[_WatsonXCallbackHandler]] = ContextVar(
    "watsonx_callback", default=None
)

class MyServiceIBMWatsonx(MyService):
    @contextmanager
    def get_langchain_callback(self) -> Generator[_WatsonXCallbackHandler, None, None]:
        cb = _WatsonXCallbackHandler()
        watsonx_callback_var.set(cb)
        yield cb
        watsonx_callback_var.set(None)
```

This works to the point that `on_llm_end` is called but `response` is `None`. I suspect that something is missing, either something that requires a further extension or addition to the custom LLM or (ideally) something else somewhere (because I cannot change this custom LLM) that allows translating the acutall response to the `LLMResult` data structure.

Or maybe there is a completely different approach I should try without using callbacks at all?

Mind this question is not specific about Watsonx but interesting generally for custom LLM.